# Bug em trecho de código em linha contendo apenas um backslash

Tags: suporte, comentários, markdown

#### Problema

Hoje ao [comentar minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85969/seguran%C3%A7a-em-formul%C3%A1rio/85977#comment173135_85974) tive que colocar um *backslash* (barra invertida) em um comentário em trecho de código  `\`, porém ela não aparecia, pois esse carácter também é um escape no *markdown*, tentei usar `\\` porém aparecia as duas barras em vez de apenas uma (testei agora e apareceu só uma, mas sem a formatação de código), a única solução foi usar um espaço após a barra: `\`.

Obs.: Aqui na pergunta não "bugou".

#### Ilustração

[image: Bug com a backslash nos comentários do StackOverflow em Português]

Answer (score 10):

A [solução](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156774/167534) é bizarra porque o suporte a markdown em comentários é limitado:

```
``\``
```

Comment: Provando que funciona: ``\``

Comment: Coloca bizarro nisso, seria tão mais simples e intuitivo se funcionasse com duas barras ``\\``...